# Reload Angular 8 em arquivos js inseridos no index.html através de routerLink

Tags: angular, route

Preciso reiniciar o angular, Se estou em qualquer outra página, e clico no routerLink, vou para a página homepage normalmente, porém, alguns elementos que dependem de arquivos javascript ou jquery de bibliotecas não são carregados, eles são carregados na primeira vez junto ao index.html, e depois disso, ao navegar no sistema de rotas, e retornar a homepage, já não é mais carregado.

Detalhando o problema abaixo:

Sou redirecionado para minha homepage normalmente, porem estou utilizando umas bibliotecas de javascript que são inseridas no index.html. por exemplo:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <base href="/">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300,400,400italic,700|Oxygen:400,300,700'
    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/favicons/Icon@2x.png">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/foundation.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/animate.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/animsition.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/icomoon.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/pogo-slider.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/responsive.css">


  <script src="assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="assets/js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/vendor/what-input.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/foundation.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/functions.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/ajax-form.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.prettySocial.js"></script>


  <script src="assets/js/jquery.smooth-scroll.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/animsition.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/headroom.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/superfish.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.pogo-slider.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.appear.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/wow.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.ajaxchimp.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/components-js/carousel-img.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/components-js/testimonial-carousel.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/components-js/expertise-carousel.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/components-js/highlight-moment.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Então o meu componente de slider, ao retornar para a homepage, fica invisível, mas se eu dou um F5, ele volta a funcionar normalmente. Eu já tentei fazer modificações na rota, como vi nos fóruns

```
imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'}) ],
```

O problema, é que a minha solução depende de um Reload forte, algo parecido como um F5 mesmo, para reatualizar todos esses componentes JavaScript que estou usando.

Em meu homepage.component.ts, já tentei utilizar uma função com location.reload(), porém ele fica em um loop infinito. Tentei também utilizar alguma forma de criar um setInterval, dar o location reload e destruir logo em seguida, mas mesmo assim persiste o loop infinito.

Estou usando um template HTML pago, que possui arquivos javascript, jquery bibliotecas para certos elementos HTML, por isso estou fazendo a utilização desta maneira, creio que não seja das melhores.

Comment: Cara Angular definitivamente não foi feito para ser utilizado com jQuery, irá ter muitos problemas com isto.

Comment: @LeAndrade Eu sei mano, mas infelizmente, a gente tem que usar esse template, por que foi uma escolha dos caras que estão pedindo o projeto, os clientes

Comment: Voce tem que adicionar ao scripts no arquivo angular json ou angular-cli.json invés de adicionar ao html diretamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

existem a meu ver três formas básicas de tratamento do slider com o jquery, que você pode utilizar para resolver seu problema o angular é um dos melhores frameworks para se trabalhar com qualquer plugin mais por ele ser muito técnico exige muito conhecimento de typescript e outras linguagens, existem três formas a meu ver:
uma é usar um pipe:
vou mostrar os exemplos através desta url:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/lydnlqeqood?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

segunda forma:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsezw8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcrisis-center%2Fcrisis-center.module.ts
este exemplo usa um animation.ts da biblioteca do angular

terceira forma você pode configurar um arquivo javascript junto com seu cdn do jquery, ou baixe os módulos do jquery diretamente no seu angular json
o arquivo é o:
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.3/assets/owl.carousel.min.css"
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
esse arquivo esta escrito em javascript:

function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("myNav").classList.toggle("menu_width");
        document
          .querySelector(".custom_menu-btn")
          .classList.toggle("menu_btn-style");
      }

depois baixe o npm i jquery e ponha ele diretamente nos módulos dos scripts
assim por exemplo:
"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" no seu arquivo angular.json